# PHP CURL connection alwasy times out, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am using the following code to get and eventually parse an xml feed. When I visit the xml feed through the browser it works just fine, yet when I try to access it with a php script using Curl I get a timeout error every single time. I have changed the timeout to as high as 500 seconds and nothing seems to matter. Is there a setting on my end I need to change or am I somehow being blocked from the server where the xml resides?

```
$url = "my url";

$tuCurl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

$xml = curl_exec($tuCurl);
```

Curl error: Operation timed out after 20000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Comment: Why do use use curl instead of file_get_contents ? If you need just to get an xml

Comment: Well because that wasn't working either, but now it apparently is.

Comment: If you're using SimpleXML, then you can pass the URL directly to its [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php).

Comment: I guess I would still like to know why Curl simply was not working? I have it working as it should with simple XML now, but I suppose to keep the question on point I am still interested in a solution.